# Why isn't 'ether proto \ip host host' a legal tcpdump expression?

Tags: networking, tcpdump

In its description of valid tcpdump expressions, the pcap-filter man pages state:

> The filter expression consists of one or more primitives.  Primitives usually consist of an id (name or number) preceded by one or more qualifiers.

In turn, these qualifiers are `type`, `dir` and `proto`. So far so good, but further down we find this:

```
     ip host host
which is equivalent to:
     ether proto \ip and host host
```

In the first case, `ip` and `host` are, respectively, `proto` and `type`. What pattern does `ether proto \ip` follow? Isn't that, as a whole, a `proto` qualifier? If so, why isn't (a properly escaped) '`ether proto \ip host host`' legal (no `and`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ether proto \ip` "\ip" is the ID. That `ether proto \ip` means the same like `ip` on the content level does not mean that both has to be syntactically equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! I should have come back here and referred to the question I later posted on the tcpdump-workers list. [Here](http://seclists.org/tcpdump/2012/q4/14) is the corresponding answer.